# How to get 'at-least' schema?

Tags: clojure, plumatic-schema

By 'at-least' I mean schema that will ignore all `disallowed-key` errors.
Consider the following snippet:

```
(require '[schema.core :as s])

(def s {:a s/Int})

(s/check s {:a 1}) ;; => nil (check passed)
(s/check s {:a 1 :b 2}) ;; => {:b disallowed-key}

(def at-least-s (at-least s))

(s/check at-least-s {:a 1}) ;; => nil
(s/check at-least-s {:a 1 :b 2}) ;; => nil
```

The first idea about implementation of `at-least` function was to conjoin `[s/Any s/Any]` entry to initial schema:

```
(defn at-least [s]
  (conj s [s/Any s/Any]))
```

but unfortunately such implementation won't work for nested maps:

```
(def another-s {:a {:b s/Int}})

(s/check (at-least another-s) {:a {:b 1} :c 2}) ;; => nil
(s/check (at-least another-s) {:a {:b 1 :d 3} :c 2}) ;; => {:a {:d disallowed-key}}
```

Is there's a possibility to get `at-least` schemas that work for nested maps as well? Or maybe `prismatic/schema` provides something out of the box that I'm missing?

Comment: No way around it other than the method you proposed. You have to walk the  structure and add it to every map you get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is something you can use from [metosin/schema-tools](https://github.com/metosin/schema-tools): `schema-tools.walk`. There is even a code that you need [in the test](https://github.com/metosin/schema-tools/blob/master/test/schema_tools/walk_test.cljc#L122):

```
(defn recursive-optional-keys [m]
  (sw/postwalk (fn [s]
                 (if (and (map? s) (not (record? s)))
                   (st/optional-keys s)
                   s))
               m))
```

Comment: this works fine. also it should be noted that `prewalk` and `postwalk` functions are available only in latest 0.8.0-SNAPSHOT